# My project doesn't appear in the jBPM WorkItem Repository after maven install

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, jbpm, parent-pom

I want to develop multiple custom WorkItem for an app and I want to store them on an instance of the jBPM WorkItem Repository.
[This tutorial](https://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2018/04/jbpm-work-items-are-really-simple.html#comment-form) describe the steps in order to get any custom work item available on this repository. I follow the tutorial without any error message, but at the end, my custom WorkItem doesn't appear in the repository.

Here is exactly the steps I've done.

1. Setup the project and create the work item

   - `git clone https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items`
   - `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jbpm -DarchetypeArtifactId=jbpm-workitems-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=7.26.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=org.jbpm.contrib -DartifactId=generated-custom-workitem -DclassPrefix=GeneratedCustom -Dversion=7.26.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeCatalog=local`
   - Import the project in my IDE and add an "Hello World" message.
2. Add my project to the jBPM WorkItem Repository

   - Add these lines to ./pom.xml in the <dependency> tag.

     `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>generated-custom-workitem</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>generated-custom-workitem</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
     </dependency>`
   - Add these lines to ./repository/pom.xml in the first <dependency> tag.

     `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.jbpm.contrib</groupId>
       <artifactId>generated-custom-workitem</artifactId>
       <type>zip</type>
     </dependency>`
   - `mvn clean install`

     I get the SUCCESS status for every module including mine and for the whole build.
   - `cd repository-springboot`

     `mvn spring-boot:run`
   - go to http://localhost:8090/repository

I expect my custom work item to be in the list.
But the work item is neither on the online repository nor in the following directory ./repository/target/repository-7.26.0-SNAPSHOT/.

What should I correct in order to have my work item available?

I get the following Warning Message for my work item:

```
[WARNING] No SupportedSourceVersion annotation found on org.jbpm.process.workitem.core.util.WidProcessor, returning RELEASE_6.
[WARNING] Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.jbpm.process.workitem.core.util.WidProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
[WARNING] The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[templateResources, widsResources, widName, generateTemplates, generateWids]'
```

I get these messages for all other work items.
There is one other warning message:

```
[WARNING] Assembly file: /Users/myuser/tests/jbpm-workitems-tests/workitem-test3/jbpm-work-items/generated-custom-workitem/target/generated-custom-workitem-7.26.0-SNAPSHOT is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
```

I try to remove the directory and compile again, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you getting the SUCCESS message after the maven build finishes? Any warning or error?

Comment: @ronnyfm I added the warning message to the question.